# Azure Pipelines YAML pipeline difference in commits per environment

Tags: azure-pipelines

In Azure Pipelines classic pipelines, a given stage has an area that shows "Difference in commits". It knows the last deployment of a given stage and therefore is able to show the difference between the last deployment of that stage and the current pipeline run.

Does such ability exist for YAML pipelines? If not in the UI, does a REST endpoint exist to show this info?

Two pieces of info would be useful:

1. The id of the previous instance of a pipeline run that was run for a given stage
2. The differences in changesets and work items between two specified pipeline runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "**Difference in commits**" feature is nor available to YAML pipelines.

For your questions:

> The id of the previous instance of a pipeline run that was run for a given stage

You can try the endpoint "[**Builds - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)"

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&$top=2&branchName={branchName}&api-version=6.1-preview.6
```

This will list the latest 2 build runs of a build pipeline for the specified branch. From the response you can get the IDs of the two runs.

> The differences in changesets and work items between two specified pipeline runs

After getting the latest 2 build runs, you can use the following endpoints:

- [**Builds - Get Changes Between Builds**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)
- [**Builds - Get Work Items Between Builds**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20work%20items%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

Comment: "The 'Difference in commits' feature is nor available to YAML pipelines" is this still the case today ?